# Removing unicode \u2026 like characters in a string in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I have a string in python2.7 like this,

```
 This is some \u03c0 text that has to be cleaned\u2026! it\u0027s annoying!
```

How do i convert it to this,

```
This is some text that has to be cleaned! its annoying!
```

Comment: Based on what do you want to filter the characters? Do you only want to preserve ASCII?

Comment: @root, yes I just want to preserve the ascii

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Python 2.x

```
>>> s
'This is some \\u03c0 text that has to be cleaned\\u2026! it\\u0027s annoying!'
>>> print(s.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore'))
This is some  text that has to be cleaned! it's annoying!
```

Python 3.x

```
>>> s = 'This is some \u03c0 text that has to be cleaned\u2026! it\u0027s annoying!'
>>> s.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
b"This is some  text that has to be cleaned! it's annoying!"
```

Comment: That's just how its printed

Comment: also curious why you wrote `\\` but not `\`, isn't `\` outputs the same thing with your code ?

Comment: This also strips characters such as `ü, ä, ö` etc, which is not desired in most of the cases.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, in your code is 's' a string? If yes, then do i need to import some package to get decode and encode helper methods?

Comment: When i tried your code on my string, i get an exception which says 'str' object has not attribute 'decode'. I am using Python 3.6.6 version

Comment: Please read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data) and  [this](https://timothybramlett.com/Strings_Bytes_and_Unicode_in_Python_2_and_3.html).

Comment: This isn't working for me...The string is exactly the same.