# Mongo Insert Error - InvalidDocument - Key names must not contain the NULL byte

Tags: python, mongodb, unicode, null, pymongo

When attempting to insert the following JSON document:

```
{
  "Cmd": "Sync",
  "DeviceId": "ApplF4KLR7XXXXXX",
  "DeviceType": "iPad",
  "User": "jackXXXXX",
  "\u0003\u0001j\u0000E\\OK\u00031102699800\u0000\u0001R\u000326\u0000\u0001S\u00030\u0000\u0001WX\u00033\u0000\u0001b\u00032\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0011EF\u00034\u0000\u0001G\u000332768\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000VJM\u000326:4909\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001": true
}
```

into a mongo collection - I get the error " InvalidDocument - Key names must not contain the NULL byte".

The structure is representing a log line generated while logging MS ActiveSync POST requests towards OWA server.

Question is: What is the safest way to escape this special char and yet keep the new structure  / value as close as possible to the original.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the last field key which contains a lot of unicode characters (include the null byte `\u0000`):

```
\u0003\u0001j\u0000E\\OK\u00031102699800\u0000\u0001R\u000326\u0000\u0001S\u00030\u0000\u0001WX\u00033\u0000\u0001b\u00032\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0011EF\u00034\u0000\u0001G\u000332768\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000VJM\u000326:4909\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001
```

The question is do you want to keep the unicode in the field key? If not you could try something like

```
.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321138/removing-unicode-u2026-like-characters-in-a-string-in-python2-7).

Comment: I went for `''.join(k.split('\x00'))` instead (to replace the NULL).