# Scrapy - encoding issue - scraping out quotes

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following class:

```
class PitchforkTracks(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pitchfork_tracks"
    allowed_domains = ["pitchfork.com"]
    start_urls = [
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/tracks/?page=1",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/tracks/?page=2",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/tracks/?page=3",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/tracks/?page=4",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/tracks/?page=5",
    ]
    def parse(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="track-details"]/div[@class="row"]'):
            item = PitchforkItem()
            item['artist'] = sel.xpath('.//li/text()').extract_first()  
            item['track'] = sel.xpath('.//h2[@class="title"]/text()').extract_first()  
            yield item
```

scraping this item:

```
<h2 class="title" data-reactid="...>“Colours”</h2>
```

results, however, print like this:

```
{'artist': u'The Avalanches', 'track': u'\u201cColours\u201d'}
```

**where and how** do I strip out the `quotes`, i.e, `\u201c` and `\u201d`?

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321138/removing-unicode-u2026-like-characters-in-a-string-in-python2-7 ?

Comment: @Ben if I write:                                                                                  `item['track'] = item['track'].decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')`I get this traceback: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `parse(self, response)`, add:

```
item['track'] = sel.xpath('.//h2[@class="title"]/text()').extract_first().strip(u'\u201c\u201d')
```